# Sliding values of an array inside intervals

Tags: javascript, intervals

I ve created a array with eleven values . I am trying to slide the values of my array during intervals. What i am trying, every n ms to slide a value to the next position of the array that i ve created. Every inteval i initialize the first value, so i want the slide effect.

```
var barArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var interval = 0; 

 setInterval(function() {

    temporal = getNewValue; //getting with a function new value

    barArray[0] = temporal;

    if(interval == barArray.length)
    {
        interval = 0;
    }


            for (var i = 0; barArray.length; i++){
            // code missing
  }


}, 1000);
```

I am tried many things without finding a solution.

Output:

```
      1st interval: [76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                    
      2nd interval: [55, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      3rd interval:  [32,55, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      11th interval: [..., 32, 55, 76] 
      12th [..., 32,55] ect. `
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you want if you provided an example with your input and expected output.

Comment: getNewValue() returns a new value every one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described here is a queue. You input elements at one end and silently drop them at the other end. JavaScript arrays have functions to add and extract elements at both ends of the array (push/pop and shift/unshift).

In the end, a complete solution would be:

```
var barArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

setInterval(function() {
  barArray.unshift(getNewValue());
  barArray.pop();
}, 1000);
```